# List keeps reseting in flutter

Tags: android, mysql, flutter, dart

i am loading a list from mySQL, initial load is ok all values are also printed out fine and also displayed just fine.

> I/flutter (30729): myvar2: [Member1, Member2, Member3, Member4]

I am using https://github.com/danvick/flutter_form_builder addon.

when i move from one step to another, the values are still in the fields untill I press/select another member it resets the values to null and picks only one. After I resubmit/reselect the same or other values the list is saved again just fine untill i move out of scope and select another member. So the values are saved until i move out of scope to another step and when i pick any of members the list resets. Values from drop down are still there in site of view, so basicaly I need to repick them in order to save without nulls to mysql.

I am setting the list length from previous step so after that even if i change something the index value can get replaced.

What am i doing wrong?

> I/flutter (30729): myvar2: [null, null, Member7, null]

```
  Widget myWidget(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
      future: _members,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot) {
        List<Widget> children;
        List<String> mylist = List<String>(data.myvar1.length);

        print("myvar2: " + data.myvar2.toString());

        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          if (getStr(data.myvar1) != null && data.myvar1.length > 0) {
            children = <Widget>[
              for (var i = 0; i < data.myvar1.length; i++)
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FormBuilderCheckboxList(
                      attribute: "my_checkbox",
                      initialValue: null,
                      options: [
                        FormBuilderFieldOption(
                            value: data.myvar1[i].toString()),
                      ],
                    ),
                    FormBuilderDropdown(
                      attribute: "my_dropdown",
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: _labelFont)),
                      initialValue: getStr(data.myvar2[i]),
                      allowClear: true,
                      hint: Text('Pick member'),
                      items: snapshot.data
                          .map((members) => DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: members, child: Text("$members")))
                          .toList(),
                      onSaved: (str) {
                        mylist[i] = str;
                        data.myvar2 = mylist;
                      },
                      onChanged: (str) {
                        mylist[i] = str;
                        data.myvar2 = mylist;
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
            ];
          } else {
            children = <Widget>[Column(children: <Widget>[])];
          }
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          children = <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.error_outline,
              color: Colors.red,
              size: 60,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
              child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
            )
          ];
        } else {
          children = <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Container(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  strokeWidth: 5.0,
                ),
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                width: 60,
                height: 60,
              ),
            ),
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
              child: Text('Loading...'),
            )
          ];
        }
        return Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: children,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Thanks for response.

Comment: What kind of variable is "data"?

Comment: static MyData data = MyData(); and the following myvar1, myvar2 is var